# SharePoint calendar -need to display only today's events

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar to track employee whereabouts. Sometimes the events can span over multiple days. On a "status board" page, I need there to be a view of the calendar to only display events occurring today.

I've tried using the filer where Start Time is less than or equal to [Today] AND where End Time is greater than or equal to today.

It is still showing future events. Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you only want to display the current day's events in a traditional calendar view (as opposed to a list view), correct? If so, you should be able to achieve what you're looking for by using the 'Default Scope' setting in the calendar view where you want to apply this parameter (see screenshots). Then the default display will always show only the current day's events.

[image: Default Scope View Setting]

[image: Current Day's Events]